# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateImagetwo does not exist. i want to add two image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to add two images. I can upload one image but if I try to add two it shows an error. I want to add two images. I can upload one image but if I try to add two it shows an error. I want to add two images. I can upload one image but if I try to add two it shows an error. I want to add two images. I can upload one image but if I try to add two it shows an error. I want to add two images. I can upload one image but if I try to add two it shows an error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreTagsRequest;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //$tags = Product::all();
        //return view('products.index', compact('tags'));

        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$tag = Product::create($request->all());

        //return redirect()->route('admin.tags.index');
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'imagetwo' => 'required|imagetwo|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:512',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        if ($imagetwo = $request->file('imagetwo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImagetwo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $imagetwo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imagetwo->move($destinationPath, $profileImagetwo);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImagetwo";
        }

        Product::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }else{
            unset($input['image']);
        }

        if ($imagetwo = $request->file('imagetwo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'imagetwo/';
            $profileTmagetwo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $imagetwo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileTmagetwo);
            $input['imagetwo'] = "$profileTmagetwo";
        }else{
            unset($input['imagetwo']);
        }

        $product->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }

    function indextwo(){
        //return DB::select("select * from  products");
       //DB::table('products')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
       return Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

}
}
```

Comment: Where your mass store function? Are you using store function to upload multiple images also?
What error are you getting? please give some more information, and don't just copy and paste the same sentence.

Comment: yes i have used store function i want to uplod  two image at a time one for real image and other for logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove imgTwo from your validation because it does not exist, why would you put it here? tell me the reason so I can provide solution

```
'imagetwo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:512',
```

Comment: I want to add another image here one for real image and imagetwo for logo

Comment: did you changed this line?

Comment: no i need this line or something else to add one more image

Comment: You don't have to remove the line but put it like the answer, you have to just remove ```imagetwo```

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer. Thank you